# Privacy error after changing nginx config

Tags: nginx

We have a website that was previously available under 3 addresses

```
report.example.com
www.live.example.com
live.example.com
```

all working with https and http and using letsencrypt certs.

It's been decided that the site will only be available under 1 address - live.example.com

The nginx config is setup as follows

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name report.example.com www.live.example.com live.example.com;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name report.example.com www.live.example.com live.example.com;
...
}
```

I have changed this to the following:-

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name report.example.com www.live.example.com;
   return 301 $scheme://live.example.com$request_uri;
}


server {
listen 80;
server_name live.example.com;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name live.example.com;
...
}
```

However when I try and navigate the site with the new config I get

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.live.example.com (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

The certificate is the same, so contains all the correct details.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that as they're on the same server I had to include the certificate details in the old virtualhost as well as the new one